# Any permutation can be only either even or odd.

Tags: abstract-algebra, sequences-and-series, permutations

A permutation can't be both **even and Odd**. How??
Is their any proof?? 
Kindly tell me.!

Thanks beforehand

Comment: See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/361822/odd-even-permutations?rq=1) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/94346/proof-that-no-permutation-can-be-expressed-both-as-the-product-of-an-even-number?rq=1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a permutation $\pi$ we define
$$\sigma(\pi) = |\{(i, j) : i < j \textrm{ and } \pi(i) > \pi(j)\}| \mod 2$$

It is easy to show inductively that $\sigma$ is $1\mod 2$ iff $\pi$ can be expressed as the product of a odd number of transpositions. By showing every transposition changes $\sigma$ by one. Once you have convinced yourself of this it follows that the parity of permutation is well defined.