# Why are Even and Odd permutations well-defined?

Tags: abstract-algebra, definition

I'm currently studying for a theory exam in Abstract Algebra. One question is about first defining the concepts of even and odd permutations and then explain why these concepts are well-defined. So, I find this a bit difficult and I'm wondering if you guys can help me out?

Why are Even and Odd permutations well-defined?

Thank You

Comment: Related (if not duplicate): [Proof that no permutation can be expressed both as the product of an even number of transpositions and as a product of an odd number of transpositions](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/94346/42969)

Comment: How do you define an even and an odd permutation?

Comment: To start off, you can write out the definition of even and odd permutations you're working with, and then tell us which part of the definition requires additional explanation.

Comment: See Cartier's paper https://www.e-periodica.ch/cntmng?pid=ens-001:1970:16::12

Answer (score 1):

The definitions of *even* and *odd* that I'm familiar with have to do with expressing a permutation as a product of transpositions.

Specifically, every permutation $\sigma$ can be expressed as a product of transpositions $\tau_1 \tau_2 \cdots \tau_n$. Then $\sigma$ is even if $n$ is even, and $\sigma$ is odd if $n$ is odd, where $n$ is the number of transpositions appearing in the product.

The problem is that there are lots of ways of expressing a permutation as a product of transpositions. For example
$$(1~~2~~3) = (1~~3)(1~~2) = (2~~1)(2~~3) = (1~~2)(1~~3)(2~~3)(2~~1)$$
So you need to show that an even permutation $\sigma$ doesn't magically become odd just by expressing it in a different way as a product of transpositions—that is, you need to show that if *some* expression of $\sigma$ as a product of transpositions has an even (resp. odd) number of transpositions in the product, then *all* such expressions do.

Comment: Ok! This is good. Thanks!