# Why is $(ab)(bc) = (ac)(ab)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

If $\epsilon = \beta_1\beta_2 \cdots \beta_r$
, where the $b$’s are $2$-cycles, then $r$ is even.

The following is part of a proof of the above theorem.

> *proof*.
>
> Clearly $r\neq1$, since a $2$-cycle is not the identity. If $r=2$, we are done. So, we suppose that $r>2$, and we proceed by induction. Suppose that the rightmost $2$-cycle is $(ab)$. Then, since $(ij) = (ji)$, the product $\beta_{r-1}\beta_r$ can be expressed in one of the following forms:
>
> $\epsilon = (ab)(ab)$,
>
> $(ab)(bc) = (ac)(ab)$,
>
> $(ac)(cb) = (bc)(ab)$,
>
> $(ab)(cd)=(cd)(ab)$.

How do we get the second form,$(ab)(bc) = (ac)(ab)$, given that $(ij)=(ji)$?

Comment: Both equal $(a\,b\,c)$.

Comment: There are only three symbols... you can just look at where they all map for both maps.

Comment: Why not track the image of each element in $\{a,b,c\}$ by $(ab)(bc)$ and by $(ac)(ab)$, and compare them?

Comment: Comparing them, I see why they both are essentially equivalent to $(a b c)$, but I thought that there was a way to prove it without using direct computation.

Comment: My guess is that the proof cites the fact that $(ij) = (ji)$ in order to explain why $(ca)(ab)$ and $(cb)(ab)$ are not listed as separate cases from $(ac)(ab)$ and $(bc)(ab).$ Otherwise it seems pointless to mention that fact.

Comment: @DavidK: That makes sense.

Comment: You might also want to take a look at this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/46403/9464