# Is $\sigma$ odd or even? Is $\tau $ odd or even?

Tags: linear-algebra, permutations, parity

This problem is taken from  Hoffman kunz linear algebra   section $5.3$  page no $155$

Let $\sigma$  and $\tau$  be the permutations of degree $4$ defined by

$$\sigma1= 2, \sigma2= 3,\sigma3= 4, \sigma3= 4$$

$$\tau1=3,\tau2=1,\tau3=2,\tau4=4$$

$(a)$ Is $\sigma$  odd or even? Is $\tau $ odd or even?

My attempt :$\sigma1= 2, \sigma2= 3,\sigma3= 4, \sigma3= 4 \implies \begin{pmatrix}1&2&3&4\\2&3&4&1\end{pmatrix}$

$$\sigma=(1234)$$

$$\sigma=\underbrace{(1234)}_{4 \text{number}}$$

$4$  is even $\implies  \sigma$ is even

similarly $\tau=(132)$ ,$\tau=\underbrace{(132)}_{3 \text{number}}$
$3$ is odd  implies  $\tau$  is odd

Comment: An odd length cycle is an even permutation. An even length cycle is an odd permutation. This follows from the definition of the parity of a permutation. Count the inverted pairs. Or write them as products of 2-cycles and count whether you need an even or an odd number of factors. Remembering that a 2-cycle is an odd permutation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the first issue here is that you need to look up the definition of odd and even permutations. Look through the [answers on this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/361822/odd-even-permutations) for that.

If you need help breaking up the permutations into transpositions look at the [accepted answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/319979/how-to-write-permutations-as-product-of-disjoint-cycles-and-transpositions).

Can you take it from here?